# ASP .NET Core Web Application Object reference error with Chrome v80

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core

I create an ASP .NET Core Web Application with ASP .NET Core 2.1 in latest Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.9.20. I add zero line of code. It builds without error, but it shows below error when I clicks 'IIS Express' to run it. It shows even before the break point in Main function hits, which makes me could not debug it. Any idea? Thanks.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

[image]

After more attempts, it works with IE 11 (version 11.0.175). But not Chrome Version 80.0.3987.122 (Official Build) (64-bit), but, why?
 [image]

Comment: try debugging the program with IIS EXpress, simply change IIS Express to the name of your program, this way kestrel kicks in, maybe the problem is with you ISS Express

Comment: What's your `launchSettings.json` ? Check your applicationUrl.